# How to expand (interpolate) an array element in a string

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

This will surely be easy-goings for someone. When I reference an array item in a string, it is not producing the desired result. I expected the last statement to produce a string containing "abc", but it does not.

```
PS C:\src\powershell> $mylist = @("abc", "def")
PS C:\src\powershell> $mylist
abc
def
PS C:\src\powershell> $mylist[0]
abc
PS C:\src\powershell> $mylist[1]
def
PS C:\src\powershell> "$mylist[0]"
abc def[0]s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>Note: While this answer covers many aspects of string interpolation in PowerShell, a more comprehensive treatment of that topic can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375).</sup>

When embedding variable references in double-quoted strings, only *simple variable references* can be embedded without enclosing the expression in the so-called subexpression operator, `$(...)`:

```sh
PS> $mylist = @("abc", "def") # define an array

PS> "$mylist[0]" # WRONG: $mylist (the whole array) is expanded, and "[0]" is a literal.
abc def[0]

PS> "$($mylist[0])" # OK: $(...) ensures that the subscript is recognized.
abc
```

---

To be more precise, **you can *directly* embed** the following variable references **in *double-quoted* strings / here-strings** in order to have them expanded (interpolated):

- a **variable referenced *by name only***; e.g., `"I'm $HOME."`
- a **variable with a *scope specifier***; e.g., `"I'm on a spiritual $env:PATH."`

To ***disambiguate* a variable name** from subsequent characters, **enclose it in `{...}`**; e.g.,
`"I'm ${HOME}:"`
Note that without `{...}`, the final `:` would have been interpreted as part of the variable name, and would have caused an error.
Alternatively, you could escape the `:` as `` `: `` and, similarly, **use `` `$ `` to escape (create a *literal*) `$`**.

**For *everything else***, including **accessing an array variable's *subscript*** or an **object variable's *property***, you need the **subexpression operator, `$(...)`**.
Note that **`$(...)` allows you to embed *entire command lines*** in a string; e.g.:

```sh
PS> "Today is $((Get-Date).ToString('d'))."
Today is 10/13/16.                         # en-US culture
```

<sup>Documentation note: [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) covers string interpolation, but, as of PSv5, not in-depth.</sup>

---

For ***alternatives* to string interpolation (expansion)** for building strings, see [Ansgar Wiecher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40033182/45375).

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell doesn't recognize more complex variable constructs (e.g. index operations (`$mylist[0]`) or property/method access (`$mylist.Count`)) when expanding variables in strings. It will simply expand the variable and leave the rest of the string alone. Hence the expression `"$mylist[0]"` becomes `"abc def[0]"`.

Basically you have three options to deal with this limitation:

- Use a [subexpression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx):

  ```
  "-$($mylist[0])-"
  ```
- Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx):

  ```
  "-{0}-" -f $mylist[0]
  ```
- Use string concatenation:

  ```
  "-" + $mylist[0] + "-"
  ```

Of course there are also more "exotic" approaches, like using the `-join` operator:

```
"-", $mylist[0], "-" -join ""
```

or replacement operations:

```
'-%x%-' -replace '%x%', $mylist[0]
'-%x%-'.Replace('%x%', $mylist[0])
```

but those already verge on obfuscation.